# At what starting angle will a billiard ball hit a pocket?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry

Let's say you have a square pool table with one pocket.

At what angles can you hit the ball to make it hit the pocket? What relation do these angles hare?

Constraints:

- Table is square: $\ell=b$.
- Frictionless
- Bouncing of ball of the sides is ideal
- Ball starts in the lower left corner.
- Pocket is in upper left corner.
- Pocket is 1x ball diameter.
- Pocket will accept a ball from any approaching angle.

Comment: If the whole thing is frictionless and ideal wouldn't the ball keep on bouncing untill it pockets ? So isn't a better question: at what angles can't you pocket? Or at what angles will the ball pocket in 5 bounces or less ?

Comment: I was just writing a similar comment to @Nick's: on a frictionless square table with ideal bouncing off the sides, I'd say any direction that isn't parallel to any of the sides will eventually lead the ball to that top left corner.

Comment: If there might be more pockets the case will probably change, maybe a sketch or something ?

Comment: "Pocket is 1x ball diameter." and "Pocket will accept a ball from any approaching angle." seem contradictory (by a factor of maybe even $\sqrt{2}$). I also think that this question, depending on how it is corrected, belongs to Math SE, given that everything is ideal and this gives all sorts of considerations regarding rational/irrational numbers, measures, etc. Methinks. (My intuition is that _almost none_ of the angles will get you there precisely.)

Comment: Agreed with Gugg. There is no physics in this question.

Comment: This is a question in physics, but not newtonian mechanics. I think it
may be related to Olbers' Paradox (why is the sky black at night?). I am checking to be sure.

Comment: It was somewhat more physics related if they would've asked the equivalent(more physical) optics question.

Comment: @Wouter Your comment is wrong as shown in my answer. There is a dense set of angles that miss the pocket systematically by a value that has a lower bound, meaning that you cannot get arbitrarily close to the pocket for any chosen such angle.

Comment: @babou Yeah I had some doubts myself shortly after posting that comment. My first idea was that all angles should eventually reach the pocket, but then I realized that's probably only true if the pocket has some finite size (isn't a mathematical point). Would I be correct to state you'll come arbitrarily close to the pocket for every angle but will only actually reach it for the angles you described in your answer?

Comment: @Nick The ball may never pocket with a random shot (cardinality
argument). Actually it is a zero probability that it will if the
pocket allows no error. Regarding the number of bounces, there has to
be an odd number of them, and for any odd number n, the number of
angles with at most n bounces is (n+1)(n+3)/4.

Comment: @Wouter The answer to your last question is no: you may miss without getting arbitrarily close. Actually I
give in my answer a denumerable set of angles for which you will never
get arbitrarily close to the pocket, which is also dense in the set of
possible angle.

Comment: @babou I probably need to freshen up my knowledge of metric spaces and accompanying concepts, but wouldn't the fact that this set is dense in the set of possible angles mean that you will in fact get arbitrarily close? Or wait, that's what you're talking about with the error increasing over the long distance, right? Can that be made more rigorous with an actual mathematical proof? I'm finding it hard to think about an infinitesimal error growing into a finite one over a finite distance. Unless of course the distance isn't finite. (I'm sorry for rambling, I'm sort of thinking out loud here)

Comment: @Wouter Actually, I did formalize it, though I did not get into details
regarding computation. For any angle in the bad set, there is a lower
bound in the distance between the trajectory and the pocket position.
This minimal distance can be computed from the ratio that defines the
tangent of the angle, though I did not look for the formula. Of course
I avoided infinitesimals (such as multiplying very small and very
big) in that case since I am talking of finite minimal distance. No
deep calculus there or advanced metric spaces (long forgotten for me).

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'll have to mull it over some other time, because I don't seem able to immediately get to that sweet candy at the end of the tunnel of thought - and I don't really have the time to cover a lot of distance in it either. :) If I can't figure it out on my own later, I'll probably ping you in chat or something, if you don't mind?

Comment: Hello. Please note that Homework questions are supposed to supposed to show more effort. For more details, please see the [Homework Policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: @babou I should have paid more attention to the countability of the corners of the pockets indeed. My excuses !

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I was doubting between posting on math or physics, but I agree that making everything perfect makes it more a math question. I have some answer-specific comments, I'll post them below. Btw, it was not homework, the question came up during a game of pool. Which makes it even less serious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the angles that work.
You just pave the plane with pool tables so that 2 tables that share a
side are mirror images with respect to that side. Then  you put a ball
on one of the tables, and aim for all the pockets.

You actually notice that since the pocket is in a corner, it will be
shared by four tables.  This amount to putting the ball at coordinate
(0,0) in the plane, and the pockets at coordinates (2i, 2j+1) for all
integer values (positive and negative) of i and j. So the angles are
arctg(2j+1 / 2i) for all integer values of i and j, with i non null,
plus the angles $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, in the positive angular direction from the X axis.

To avoid special cases here, it is probably better to use arccotg(2i /
2j+1), so as to avoid zero as denominator.

The first comment by @Nick is not quite true. If you require exact
angles, you will not have all of them because you have only a
denumerable number of them that work, as the above set of ratios 2i /
2j+i (reversed to avoid infinity) is a denumerable set, but you have a
continuous set of angles in [0, 2$\pi$]. However, it is almost true as
tangent (or rather cotangent here) is a continuous function, and the
set of ratios is a dense subset of the reals. That means that any
angle that is not the above defined set can be approximated as
precisely as you want by an angle in the set.

However, to approximate angles, you need to consider pockets that are very far away, so that whatever small error is made on the angle will be amplified by distance, so that the pocket may actually be missed by a wide margin. I have not yet worked out whether that can be be approximated too, but I very much doubt it.

Indeed, the  angles 0 and $\pi$ follows the X axis and never get
arbitrarily close to a pocket, even  by going far enough. This is also clearly true for the diagonals (x=y). The same is true, though with increasingly smaller minimal distance to pockets,
for all angles defined by arctg (2j+1 / 2i+1), for all i and j. These
angles are as many as the succesful ones.

These very special pockets are very tolerant on velocity angle, but probably not on position. The idea is that the ball is point-like.

In this abstract problem, where the balls is dimensionless, I considered
that it is possible to bounce from the lowest corner sides. If you do
not want that, you just keep the first quadrant with arctg(2j-1 /
2i) for i and j positive integers, and you add $\pi/2$ for the direct shot.

Another interesting fact is that the number of bounces is necessarily
an odd number, if you do not allow bouncing in the initial corner, i.e., if you consider only the first quadrant.

Given a fixed positive number n of bounces, and considering only the first quadrant, there are $(n+1)/2$ solutions which are defined as $arctg((2j-1) /
2i)$ for $i$ and $j$ positive such that $i+j=(n+3)/2$

Use a long cue, some pockets are far away, and as they say, infinity is
very far, especially at the end.

Comment: **... and thanks for all the votes.** Not that science was ever a matter of opinion, so that voting should rather be reserved to politics.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. If the successful and unsuccessful set are both denumerable, will they form a continuous set together? If not, what are the missing angles?

Comment: ,@Docman No, finite union of denumerable sets only give denumerable
sets. The fact that these two sets are dense means that any direction
may be approximated with whatever precision you want both by a
succesful direction and by an unsuccessful one. Life is full of
mystery. Essentially this is because the tangents for both sets
represent each time a sizeable part of the rationals. Actually there
is a third (dense) set, with unsuccessful direction, defined by
$arctg(2j/(2i-1))$ for $i,j\gt 0$. The three sets are disjoint, and
their union is the set of all angles with a rational tangent.

Comment: @Docman So what is missing. Very simply all the angles with a tangent
that is not rational. And there are continuously many of them. They
correspond to directions that get arbitrarily close to the pocket if
you wait long enough, without ever quite making it ... else we would be
in the rational case (I did not check formally the "arbitrarily close", but I think the proof is easy).

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a math question. Babou's answer is correct.
$$\forall i,j \in W | \theta = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2j-1}{2i} \right)$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle with the axis to the right. Here is an illustration for one example:

[image]

Where the pool is the square "MVWA".